# Why resources are being shared among exclusive node labels?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm having 5 different node labels and all of them are exclusive and each belongs to the same queue. When I'm submitting spark job on different node labels, resources are being shared between them but that should not be the case when using exclusive node labels.

What could be the possible reason?

**HDP Version - HDP-3.1.0.0**

My Spark Submit -

`bash $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --packages net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:0.9.0,com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.6.0 --master yarn --queue prodQueue --conf  "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions= -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4g -XX:NewRatio=1"  --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled=false --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 --conf spark.task.maxFailures=40 --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=8m --conf spark.driver.memory=3g --conf spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold=5000 --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=60s --conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.20 --conf spark.ui.port=7070 --conf spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=10 --conf spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR --conf spark.port.maxRetries=100 --conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=280 --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.cleaner.ttl=600 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 6g --num-executors 8 --conf spark.yarn.am.nodeLabelExpression=amNodeLabel --conf spark.yarn.executor.nodeLabelExpression=myNodeLabel  my-application.jar`

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please show your Spark submit command

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added the submit command above. Please have a look.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "resources are shared"

Comment: As per the above command, when I'm submitting this job to **myNodeLabel** it should use the resource of that node label only but It's using the resource from some other node labels also.
FYI all node labels are exclusive.